# Converting SubQuery to Join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables Employee and salary
Employe => ID, Name Fields

Salary => Sid, EId(Foriegn key) , Month, Salary

```
Employee 
ID  Name
1   a
2   b
3   c

Salary 
Sid Eid Month Salary
1    1   Jan   10
2    2   Jan   10
3    3   Jan   10 
4    1   Feb   10
5    3   Feb   10
6    1   Mar   10
7    2   Mar   10
```

Need to find the Employees who have not got salary in month of march and Using Join only since I need optimization

I have search stmt using sub query as

```
select E.Name from Employee where E.ID not in (Select EID from salary where month ='mar' );
```

for optimization purposed I was asked to convert this to join

I tried using

```
Select E.Name from Employee E left join Salary S on E.ID = S.EID where S.EID = null;
```

But this is not what I desired I need only employees who was not given salary in month of **March** Only.

Comment: My SubQuery Works fine

Comment: This solution is fine why do you need join query?

Comment: Optimization is required in this case. Performance and other factor drives the current Web and DB world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.Name
FROM Employee E
    LEFT JOIN salary S
        ON E.Id = S.EID
          AND S.month ='mar'
GROUP BY E.Name
HAVING COUNT(E.Id) != COUNT(S.EID)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b49ad/4)**

Comment: group by e.name can be erroneous, as there can be similar name employees.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.Name
FROM Employee E
    LEFT JOIN salary S
        ON E.Id = S.EID
          AND S.month ='mar'
GROUP BY E.Id
HAVING COUNT(E.Id) != COUNT(S.EID)
```

try this.